# How to use DESCRIBE inside SERVICE in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I want to use `DESCRIBE` inside `SERVICE` clause of a SPARQL query. How can one do that?

I tried the following query but it returned with a syntax error.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

DESCRIBE :Tom_Cruise WHERE {

SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql/>{

}
}
```

Comment: What is the goal of this query? I don't see the benefits compared to using the standard `DESCRIBE <URI>` with the endpoint set as URL in your client code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, quite.

(Your initial query had `SERVICE` inside `DESCRIBE` (not `DESCRIBE` inside `SERVICE`), and though it's a valid construction, the empty graph pattern inside the `SERVICE` clause asks DBpedia for *every* triple it has [which will time out and/or stop after a limited number of records is returned, due to service limits on that public endpoint], and then asks your local SPARQL processor to use *its* `DESCRIBE` routine on whatever data you did get, so it's virtually certain you won't get what you want in the end. I don't know where you tried to execute it, nor what syntax error you got, so cannot analyze that error any further.)

`DESCRIBE` is a [SPARQL query form](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QueryForms), not a clause within a `SELECT`.  It's only [informatively specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) (i.e., what it delivers varies substantially from implementation to implementation).

Also, the `SERVICE` clause doesn't take a full query as an argument -- it takes a graph pattern.

So, you could do something like this --

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

DESCRIBE :Tom_Cruise
WHERE 
  {
    SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql/>
      {
         :Tom_Cruise   ?p  ?o .
         ?s  ?p  :Tom_Cruise
      }
  }
```

-- but that will not return the same as executing this directly on [the DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/), because of how that endpoint implements `DESCRIBE` --

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

DESCRIBE :Tom_Cruise
```

Comment: The initial query is a valid SPARQL query with an empty graph pattern inside the SERVICE clause - at least according to the grammar (https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#grammar) and the SPARQL validator (http://sparql.org/query-validator.html). But it's not clear which syntax error he got and from where...on DBpedia you get an `Virtuoso 42000 Error SQ070:SECURITY: Must have select privileges on view DB.DBA.SPARQL_SINV_2`, but this looks more like some restrictions with the public service.

Comment: Yes, DBpedia disallows outbound Federated SPARQL.